# How to add an if conditional inside a lambda function to determine what string concatenate to another string?

Tags: python, regex, string, if-statement, lambda

```py
def weeks_to_days(input_text, nro_days_in_a_week = 7):
    input_text = re.sub(
                r"(\d+)[\s|]*(?:semanas|semana)",
                lambda m: str(int(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week) + " dias ",
                input_text)

    return input_text


input_text = "en 1 semana quizas este lista, aunque viendole mejor, creo esta muy oxidada y seguro la podre poner en marcha en 3 semanas"

print(weeks_to_days(input_text))
```

The problem with this lambda function is that it always puts `"dias"` in the plural no matter how many.

How do I place this conditional **inside the lambda function** to determine if it is `"dias"` in the plural or if it is `"dia"` in the singular depending on the amount

```py
if   (str(m[1]) != "1"): str(int(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week) + " dias "
elif (str(m[1]) == "1"): str(int(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week) + " dia "
```

Taking that string from the example, we should get this output:

```
"en 7 dias quizas este lista, aunque viendole mejor, creo esta muy oxidada y seguro la podre poner en marcha en 21 dias"
```

In this case, since they are weeks, they will always remain in the plural, but assuming that the week lasts 1 day as a parameter, then the problem would be there.

Comment: Why do you need that if you are not matching a float value before `semanas`? You can't have 1 day because you can only match `0`, `1`, etc. *weeks*. Another question: what do you match with `[\s|]*`? Really zero or more whitespaces or pipe chars? Or did you mean to just match zero or more whitespaces?

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/CYYsjk, does it help?

Comment: Can you just write a *full* function instead of using a lambda?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I used the `[\s|]*` as one or more whitespaces, Also in your answer I saw that you did it differently but it worked perfectly, mmmm  `[\s|]*`  is equal to  `\s*` ?

Comment: No, `[\s|]` matches a whitespace or `|`. `\s` matches whitespaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re
def weeks_to_days(input_text, nro_days_in_a_week = 7):
    input_text = re.sub(
                r"(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*semanas?\b",
                lambda m: str(int(float(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week)) + (" dia" if round(float(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week) == 1 else " dias"),
                input_text)

    return input_text


input_text = "en 0.142858 semanas quizas este lista, aunque viendole mejor, creo esta muy oxidada y seguro la podre poner en marcha en 3 semanas"
print(weeks_to_days(input_text))
```

The regex is now `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*semanas?\b`:

- `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 1: one or more digits followed with an optional sequence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `semanas?` - `semana` and an optional `s` char
- `\b` - a word boundary.

The `lambda m: str(int(float(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week)) + (" dia" if round(float(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week) == 1 else " dias")` replacement now concatenates:

- `str(int(float(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week))` - the number of days that is the Group 1 multiplied by the `nro_days_in_a_week`
- `(" dia" if round(float(m[1]) * nro_days_in_a_week) == 1 else " dias")` adds `dia` if the result of Group 1 value and `nro_days_in_a_week` multiplication is rounded to 1, else, `dias` is used.